Four five-letter words from the 20 most common letters
The 20 most common letters in English are
ETAOINSHRDLCUMWFGYPB
Are there four five-letter words that use all 20 of the letters once?


 THING FACES BUMPY WORLD

There are certainly many more solutions.

Commenting on yours since it was the first answer. 18256 answers at:
https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=ETAOINSHRDLCUMWFGYPB+&language=english&t=500&d=4&include=&exclude=&n=5&m=5&a=n&l=n&q=n&k=1

@JoelRondeau So only 18250ish more answers to be posted here...!

While scrolling through the linked page, rot13(GEHZC TBYSF JVAQL ORNPU) just stuck in my head...
